# Handle DST Root CA X3 Let's Encrypt SSL certificate version at runtime with Java

Tags: java, ssl, websocket

I'm implementing a websocket server to which connect some clients via websocket.

It works well via browser but not from java code.

From java, on Linux pc, this line:

```
WebSocket socket = WebSockets.newSocket(WebSockets.toSecureWebSocketUrl("myDomain", 8080));
```

throws this error:

> Failed to send an opening handshake request to the server: PKIX path
> building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

I know that client side the websocket host and port are ok because when I try it while the websocket server is not active, the error message is correctly "connection refused".

After reading on web I found that the certificate generated by certbot is the version DST Root CA X3, that [expired on sept 2021](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/).

Maybe the java error is related to that old version, because of its deprecation and then it throw that error?

I need, at runtime (also when the App will be downloaded from Play Store) that the App trusts my ssl certificate even if its version is DST Root CA X3 or every other format released by Let's Encrypt, without the need to release a new App version every time the certificate is renewed on the server.

I already tried to renew the certificate on the server with certbot but it still uses the DST Root CA X3 version for the new one.

Here is my Java client code (I'm using the libGDX framework with Java on Android Studio):

```
package ...textwebsockets;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
import com.github.czyzby.websocket.WebSocket;
import com.github.czyzby.websocket.WebSocketListener;
import com.github.czyzby.websocket.WebSockets;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

public class TestWebSockets extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public final String LOG_TAG = "LOG_TestWebSockets";

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        
        // https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-websockets/tree/master
        WebSocket socket = WebSockets.newSocket(WebSockets.toSecureWebSocketUrl("myDomain", 8080));
        socket.setSendGracefully(true);
        socket.addListener(new WebSocketListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) { ... }

            @Override
            public boolean onClose(WebSocket webSocket, int closeCode, String reason) { ... }

            @Override
            public boolean onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String packet) { ... }

            @Override
            public boolean onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, byte[] packet) { ... }

            @Override
            public boolean onError(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable error) {
                Gdx.app.log(LOG_TAG, "onError: " + error.getCause().getMessage() + "; " + error.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        });
        
        socket.connect();
    }

    ...
}
```

Server side code (node.js on a DigitalOcean VPS Droplet with Linux):

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

const server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem')
}, app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server: server});

wss.on('connection', function (ws) { ... });

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Listening on 8080');
});

... // various wss.on* methods
```

I start the server with `npm start`.

The website code:

```
<script>
    const wss = new WebSocket('wss://myDomain:8080');
    ... // various wss.on* methods
</script>
```

In the browser network console a 101 line appears and receives the server messages. (I also send messages to the server but I removed that code here because not relevant for this post).

I already read many SO answers but almost all of them suggest to manually use a .pem file.

I tested the ssl at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=myDomain with an A result:

[image]

Comment: @nikita-rybak you had a similar issue years ago, can you help me on this plesae?

Comment: Did you include the new X3 certificate into the `cacerts` store in Java? The trust path should end with a certificate that you explicitly trust after all. You should probably  upgrade your Java as a default `cacerts` is part of the distribution.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes just tried `sourceCompatibility = 1.8` and 1.11 but the error is the same (in both buile.gradle:core and build.gradle:desktop)

Comment: Yeah, `sourcecompatibility` is not going to add a certificate to the cert store.